# .CDR to .SVG Convert Using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I am on CentOS 6.4 and trying to convert .CDR to .SVG Convert Using ImageMagick using SSH command.

1. my 1.cdr file is in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/test/1.cdr
2. once converted to SVG it should be created in the same folder

Tried the following command:

```
convert /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/test/1.cdr image.svg
```

The Error I am getting is:

> sh: mplayer: command not found convert: Delegate failed `"mplayer"
>   "%i" -really-quiet -ao null -vo png:z=3' @
>   delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1032. convert: missing an image filename`
>   image.svg' @ convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2800.

Not sure what does that mean ?

Comment: el.pescado check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/22600/open-or-convert-cdr-files

Comment: user580950: that's special case

Comment: I mean, that was scanned image. Moreover that's still not the optimal method.

Answer (score 2):

In order to convert CDR files you need to install `uniconvertor` for CDR delegate.

List of all delegates:

```
convert -list delegate
```

By default it outputs:

```
cdr =>          "uniconvertor" "%i" "%o.svg"; mv "%o.svg" "%o"
```

Install `uniconvertor`. For example, on Ubuntu it’s:

```
sudo apt-get install python-uniconvertor
```

Then run:

```
convert image.cdr -flatten -thumbnail '512x512' image.png
```

Or, with zoom cropping:

```
convert image.cdr -flatten -thumbnail '512x512^' -gravity center -crop 512x512+0+0 +repage image.png
```

And you’re done.

I convert to PNG here but you may use your own output format.

Answer (score 0):

`python-uniconvertor` is part of `inkscape`.

It does not exist by itself.

Ubuntu/Mint recently removed all the old Python stuff, for Corel Draw I have to fire up the WinXP VM & Corel and export something Linux understands, usually PNG, a favourite

`CDR` & WMF files are pretty much dead to Linux, `ImageMagick` can still handle `WMF` though.

Comment: Uniconvertor might be bundled with Inkscape (now or in the past) , but it certainly does exist by itself: https://sk1project.net/uc2/ , https://github.com/sk1project/uniconvertor , https://github.com/witwall/uniconvertor